# Why are parallel select's on SQLserver slower?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I am puzzled why selecting in parallel on SqlServer is so much slower than select'ing sequentially

Also it looks like increasing parallelism (threads) will just make the delays even bigger

This small sample can reproduce the problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SqlThreading;

var repository = new Repository();
Console.WriteLine("Prefetch");
await repository.GetData(0);

var identifiers = new List<int>();
for (int i=70; i<80; i++)
    identifiers.Add(i);

Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}Sequential:");
foreach (var identifier in identifiers)
    await repository.GetData(identifier);

Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}Parallel:");
Parallel.ForEach(identifiers, new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = identifiers.Count}, async i => 
    await repository.GetData(i));
```

My repository is just this (using Dapper):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Dapper;

namespace SqlThreading
{
    public class Repository
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public Repository()
        {
            _connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = "SqlServer",
                InitialCatalog = "Database",
                IntegratedSecurity = true,
                MinPoolSize = 10,
            }.ToString();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> GetData(int id)
        {
            await using var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var result = await conn.QueryAsync($"select top 1 * from dbo.MyTable id = @id", new {id});
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Query took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

With my setup it will produce something like this:

```
Prefetch
Query took 2877 ms

Sequential:
Query took 46 ms
Query took 24 ms
Query took 23 ms
Query took 26 ms
Query took 28 ms
Query took 23 ms
Query took 24 ms
Query took 26 ms
Query took 33 ms
Query took 30 ms

Parallel:
Query took 55 ms
Query took 153 ms
Query took 154 ms
Query took 154 ms
Query took 154 ms
Query took 155 ms
Query took 155 ms
Query took 67 ms
Query took 158 ms
```

Comment: well, for one thing, there's the overhead of creating threads, and allocating the neccessary ressources. and then there's the overhead of managing concurrent access to the same resources. also: you oughta add a task-based parallel test case - start all tasks, then await all tasks, on one thread. multiple threads are best for when you _do_ something in parallel, not when you _wait for_ something in parallel.

Comment: This test has poor context - you are comparing one thing with another with no rhyme or reason; why are you testing to see if parallel single selects are quicker that series single selects? What are you trying to determine?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann in our production code we are using a threadpool. This was just to illustrate the problem

Comment: Spoilers: SQL Server already utilizes parallelism for queries where possible. It doesn't always do so optimally, but it generally does mean that you very quickly hit a ceiling with how much additional performance you'd squeeze out by doing things in parallel, as the only things you're parallelizing is the data transfer from the server to the client, and not the actual database I/O. That shouldn't be the issue for *this* query (since it's just a `TOP 1`), so the overhead there should be purely client-side, but you'll very much notice with practical access patterns.

Comment: @Charleh Our production code appears to process transactions slower when we add threads to our threadpool. We have narrowed the problem down to sql-server access

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes. Our DBA confirms that the additional time is not used on server I/O. Also a wireshark trace reveals that sqlserver responses arrive back at the client pretty much corresponding to ping-times. So no time spent on sql-server. So for some reason the client just slows down with parallelism. That is what I am trying to nail

Comment: Well, there is still a lot of work to be done on the SQL client side library to optimize for asynchrony; there are (or were) lots of places where the async part gets faked or inefficient mechanisms are used to wrap synchronous bits. `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` should do a little better than `System.Data.SqlClient` in this regard since it's under active development, but even then parallelizing by multiple processes is likely more effective than multiple threads (for now).

Comment: @JeroenMostert That was also my suspicion. I was not aware of the difference between Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and System.Data.SqlClient. We are using the latter. Can we just change to the Microsoft lib ?

Comment: It's highly compatible and usually dropping in the package and changing the `using`s will "just work" (that's more or less how it's designed to be used). You may run into complications if using CLR types like `SqlGeography`, since these live in incompatible assemblies (don't know if they've fixed that yet). It's worth trying, in any case. Likewise with switching to .NET Core/.NET 5, if you're not using that already -- you often get "free" performance that way.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  Just tried it.... Works great... Huge improvement. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The way you use stopwatch might also not be correct, when running sequentially you can just add up, but running parallel you can't just add up as they are potentially running at the same time. Just something to keep in mind, will probably skew the numbers a bit.

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt The StopWatch.StartNew() will create a new stopwatch object at each query. Can't see how they can interfere with each other

Comment: Another thing is that : each SELECT nead to compute an execution plan. When dealing it sequentially, the first plan is cached and then became available to the next queries. In parallel, every query needs to compute its own plan, because the plan is not yet in the cache...

Comment: @TorbenNielsen they are not interfering with each other, but in the parallel loop they execute at the same time, so you can't just tally up each result for each query. In theory in your code, all queries could run at the exact same time counting their individual execution time, but the actual time it takes to execute all of them could actually be, given your example, 158ms, which is lower then the total of all the sequential added up. You should probably measure total execution time of all queries instead of each individual query which give a more correct time I would say.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSchmidt That is why I have the Prefetch. Execution plan (and connections) will be ready before I start the code. In any case a second run of the test program would run on a prepared execution plan

Comment: In this type of queries (TOP N, FAST N), SQL Server wants to read any row as possible as fast so it uses a method which is called row goal. However, this mechanism and parallel execution plans can not get along well. This can lead to the problem. You see more details Rogue Row Goals part of this article https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/05/parallel-row-goals-gone-rogue.html As a result , we can say that a bug of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @JeroenMostert the problem propably lies in the System.Data.SqlClient where parallelism is not yet fully matured

Until it is, we will use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, which has dramatically better parallelism support

Answer (score 0):

In the parallel option it’s probably opening many more connections to SQL Server. Opening a connection is a relatively heavy operation, so they’re automatically & transparently pooled for you. In your first set of queries .NET will re-use the same connection. In the parallel option it needs to make several extra connections.

Use an Extended Events session to look at the connection IDs to confirm. Or run the parallel loop again and you’ll probably see it taking about the same time as the serial example.

It’d also be good to understand exactly what you’re trying to test. Are you trying to see the effect of parallel operations on the client or the server?

If it’s the server then you’ll want to put a proper load on it and probably more complex queries. Or a representative load of whatever you really want to do on the server. There are good free load-testing tools out there to do this much more effectively than a small test harness you write yourself.

If it’s the client then again you need to work out what you want to achieve. Run tons of small queries in parallel ... why? If they take effectively 0 time on the server there’s little point running in parallel. If they’re sending back lots of data then maybe it’s worth looking further. If they’re taking a long time but not returning much data then great, could be a case for running in parallel. Either way you should structure your tests & queries accordingly.